# How do I import or include PHP class file from a different folder?

Tags: php, object

I am having trouble including PHP classes from different folders.
SO, basically this is my structure:

**FOLDER** ------------ **FILES**

models --------------- ModelDatabase.php

views ---------------- home.php

Then, I need to include `ModelDatabase.php` inside `home.php`.
I have tried  using

```
require_once(__DIR__."models/ModelDatabase.php");
```

and other variations, but none works.

Also, I am running this on localhost in Ubuntu.

So, can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: `__DIR__` returns the current directory of the current PHP file *without an ending slash*. For example `/home/site/www`. Notice the missing slash? That means you're loading `/home/site/wwwmodels/ModelDatabase.php`. You *should* be loading `/home/site/www/models/ModelDatabase.php`.

Comment: what is the base stucture of your home dir ?

Comment: Maybe simply like this `"../models/ModelDatabase.php"`

Comment: "none of it works" is not very useful. some debugging data like the path you're actually `require`ing, copypaste the error message?

Comment: I am using php  5.5.9

Comment: can you please try this => include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/models/ModelDatabase.php');

Comment: I tried but it gives me PHP Fatal error: Class ModelDatabase not found in /var/www/site/views/home.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending in what structure you are you have to change directory

how to do this

```
i/am/in/this/dir/foo.php

//now you want to include a file in foo.php
//your includes are in the 'this' folder
//you change dir like

include("../../myInclude.php");
//that means you go two directorys back
```

other way you can handle this is to use full path

```
i/am/in/this/dir/foo.php
//is your file
include("./i/am/in/this/myInclude.php");
//includes it with a given full path
```

i would create some constants like

```
define('INC_PATH', '/i/am/in/this/');
```

and would use them like

```
require_once(INC_PATH . "myIncFile.php" );
```

Comment: the absolute path should begin with a slash

Comment: edited my post. but actually you dont need it. got many sources where i dont have a beginning slash... php is kind of friendly :D

Comment: Hi, if you don't include the slash at the beginning, then PHP assumes that the file is retrieved from the *current file's folder*, and not the root directory. Hence using a slash at the start is definitely not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys it finally worked.

Basically, I had a typo on my class name -- it was ModelsDatabase instead of ModelDatabase.
And I just used include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/models/ModelDatabase.php') as suggested by PHP Weblinindia.